How does the CPU handle stack overflow for a particular task in an OS
I know what i'm about to ask depends on the type of platform and the OS itself.
I am having difficulties understanding how an OS manages the different stack spaces for different tasks in general.
Let's say we initailze an OS with many different tasks and specify the stack size for each task. When a task is running, and data is getting pushed onto the stack and reaches the limit of the stack space size allowed for that task.
Correct me if i'm wrong, as the OS is not runnning at this point, an exception must come from the CPU first, which eventually leads to the OS getting back control. Then it can manage the memory in whatever way
How does the CPU generate an exeption when the stack limit for a particular task is exceeded? This will be a different value for each task. It must have values to compare?

I think off topic, but if it is detected at all, it is via the MMU.  If the stack is virtually mapped, an overflow will result in an invalid memory access.  Perhaps better at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/. You are asking about how processors and operating systems work, not about software development.

It is done by a virtual memory mechanism.
Each program has its own page table (prepared by the OS), which maps virtual addresses to physical ones. The CPU will check the table each time the program access memory. Some entries in the page table can be marked "Not present". When encountering such page, the CPU will trigger an interrupt/exception and jump to the OS code.
OS can purposefully mark some pages "Not present" to detect when a program accesses them - this concept is called "Guard page". OS surrounds the stack with guard pages. When the program touches such page - OS gets control. If it sees that the page is near the stack - it treats it as a stack overflow.
Note, that this mechanism is not exactly foolproof - there are a limited number of guard pages. If you overflow the stack too much at once - it is possible to jump over all guard pages and land into the heap, and the OS has no way to prevent that.

Thank you for this reply. How does the CPU check address tables? This is what confuses me. I picture only a CPU fetching, decoding and executing instructions. Checking address tables is not at OS / program level?

@Engineer999 It just reads it from memory (or from cache, if it is cached). The OS puts the physical address of the table in one of the CPU's registers, and the CPU just uses it. The table must be in a format that CPU understands (described in the CPU's manual).
Not all CPUs have virtual memory support. It is technically an advanced feature - you don't need it to make a computer. But all modern OSes require it.

Ok that's what I was wondering. Am I correct in assuming that if the CPU has an MMU and is enabled, it will perform these register checks at the CPU / hardware level when the program accesses memory? Without an MMU / Virtual memory support, this stack overflow checking is difficult to achieve?

@Engineer999 Yes.
